# how to get the selected item from html dropdown list and pass it to another controller in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I'm getting values to my `Html.Dropdownlist` like below.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 style="color: #2f6207">dfdfDestination</h2>
    @Html.DropDownList("accountID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Destination, "regCde", "Destination"))
</div>

@Html.ActionLink("SEARCH NOW", "MscHome")
```

it works fine.
now I want to get the user selected value and pass it to another controller when button clicked(`action link`)

```
public ActionResult MscHome(string accountID)
{
    ViewBag.requested = Session["search"];
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return View();
}
```

but this shows `null` value.

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: I don't use any submit button

Comment: why dont you use routeurl?

Comment: You would need to use javascript to update the `href` attribute, but why are you not just using a form (with `FormMethod.Get`)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to target the same controller first, get the value from the dropdown and then redirect to a second controller passing the value as parameter. Use **RedirectToAction** and either **TempData** or set the value as an argument in the call.

If you just return a view used by another controller, this could be okay in some cases. But if the view needs to be initialized by code located in a different controller then you'll open an empty view. That's what RedirectToAction is preventing.